# How to write a test that fails when I get a CSP blocking something

Tags: console.log, content-security-policy

I want to be able to write a test that will fail if my Content-Security-Policy blocks something in my pre-live environment.

I find this out normally by seeing something like this message in the browser console:
`Refused to connect to 'https://www.<somedoamin>.com' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: <something>`

Motivation:

So I have to manually open the console, see the error, update the CSP and redeploy.
Checking this every time is something that could be forgotten - a test would remove some human error.